# unable to setup wsgi with httpd for running python based web app

Tags: mod-wsgi

I have archlinux.

I installed `httpd` and `mod_wsgi`

and added the following in the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

after this how to put the things in the virtualhost file.

Still i tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/simha/.public_html/public_wsgi/wsgi-scripts
    <Directory "/home/simha/.public_html/public_wsgi/wsgi-scripts">
    Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks    
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have put a testing script called wsgi_app.py in the `/home/simha/.public_html/public_wsgi/wsgi-scripts` folder.

the wsgi_app.py script is

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def wsgi_app(environ, start_response):
    import sys
    output = sys.version.encode('utf8')
    status = '200 OK'
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
               ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, headers)
    yield output

# mod_wsgi need the *application* variable to serve our small app
application = wsgi_app
```

(Also i dont understand what is this code doing). i got it from archlinux.

when go to `localhost` in the browser, i get

Forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

This error is generally caused by the fact that your home directory has permissions such that other users cannot access anything in it. This will cause a problem as Apache httpd will run as a distinct user.

Move your application to a directory outside of your home directory, such as under `/var/www`.